# Best practice and/or approach to MongoDB scheme for product/price data?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose-schema

## Application Details

My application/site is Express powered with MongooseJS as the ODM for MongoDB. I have a pretty traditional product/price structure I am trying to achieve.

## Example of Document

Here is an example of what the data would look like with my current schema:

The example is a document contained inside the `products` collection.

```
_id: ObjectId("5acfe7cdecf8287c374f3fc3"),
enabled: true,
brand: 'brand_name',
name: 'product_name',
type: 'product_type',
price_history: Array
   0: Object
      _id: ObjectId("5acfe7cdecf8287c374f3fc4")
      source: "Amazon"
      price: 99.99
      date: 2018-04-12 16:12:13.420
   1: Object
      _id: ObjectId("5acfe7cdecf8287c374f3fc5")
      source: "BHPhotovideo"
      price: 120.99
      date: 2018-04-11 16:12:13.420
   etc...
```

## Predicted Documents

**Product Documents** ~ 3500 at MAX, rarely increase

**Price History Objects** Current prediction is a growth of 3-80/month per product. At the MAX annual rate a document can gain 960 objects inside of the `price_history` array. To simulated this I grew a document to where the `price_history` contained 2100 objects. This brought the document to ~198 KB.

What worries me is this is for historical price data and this can really bring issues in the future with performance/size.

## Other

The `price_history` data will be used to show the most recent price per `price_history.source` in addition to graphing per product.

I'll need to be able to do traditional queries that allow for people to filter by brand, check for historical lows, calculate deals, etc.

Answer (score 0):

As always - it depends ... on your data access patterns.

You should take in account that client will load the whole price history every time when he loads the product.

If you need to display the price history to be always visible, then nesting the array is correct approach.

If not, then consider separating the price history leaving only the current price in the product itself and load the price history only when necessary. This will reduce the initial amount of data transferred, but will require an additional request to database.